# application.conf is not loaded

Tags: spring, scala, akka

I've put `application.conf` in `src/main/resources`, but the configuration doesn't load when I run my application. I have for instance a custom Akka mailbox defined in `application.conf`. It returns an error:

```
akka.ConfigurationException: Mailbox Type [custom-mailbox] not configured.
```

How can I fix this? I'm running a test application `Test.scala` which extends App. I run it as a Scala application. Is this the problem?

### EDIT

As requested, my `application.conf`:

```
akka {
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = "INFO"
    stdout-loglevel = "INFO"

    seatclaimer-mailbox {
        mailbox-type = "com.ticketo.seating.SeatClaimer$SeatClaimerMailbox"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/general/configuration.html fully?

Comment: application.conf couldn't be loaded due to errors in it. Could you paste relevant code snippet?

Comment: I haven't read that document fully, but I don't think it would help me. I have included my `application.conf` in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The config did load but the mailbox couldn't be found.
Firstly, my addressing was incorrect.

```
Props(new SeatClaimer(seatingZone)).withMailbox("seatclaimer-mailbox")
```

`"seatclaimer-mailbox"` has to be `"akka.seatclaimer-mailbox"`.

Secondly, the location of the mailbox in `application.conf` was incorrect. I changed it to `"com.ticketo.seating.SeatClaimerMailbox"`.

Answer (score 0):

The config file must be in the classpath, but src/main/resources is not included in the default classpath which is a unmanaged resources. It means you need to add it to your project classpath manually. It's easy to do this in eclipse, or 
add `(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile) <+= baseDirectory(_ /"src/main/resources")`  to your build.sbt